# using python hash() values as a refrence number

Tags: python, hash, reference, scrapy

I'm writing a scrapy spider that collects news articles from various online newspapers. The sites in question update at least once a day, and I'm going to run the spider just as often, I need some way to filter out duplicates (i.e articles I've already scraped).

In other cases it'd be as simple as comparing reference numbers, but newspaper articles don't have any reference numbers. I was wondering if it'd be possible to hash the title using pythons hash() function and use the resulting value as a stand-in for an actual reference number, just for comparison purposes?

On the surface it seems possible, but what do you guys think?

Comment: Bear in mind that sometimes the title will change (although sometimes keeping the same URL - see e.g. http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2014-07-07/samsung-profit-misses-estimates-as-cheap-phones-struggle.html).

Comment: Sounds OK to me.  You may still have to handle possibilities of a hash collision

Comment: Another caveat : hash function is architecture dependent, so if this job runs across multiple worker nodes you might want to keep that in mind

Comment: Also some articles can get updated, so it may be better to calculate the hash of title and body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, but I'd not use `hash()` for this, as `hash()` is optimised for a different task and can lead too easily to collisions on larger texts (different inputs resulting in the same hash value).

Use a [cryptographic hashing scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) instead; the [`hashlib` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) gives you access to MD5 and other algorithms and produce output that is far less likely to produce collisions.

For your purposes, [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) will do just fine:

```
article_hash = hashlib.md5(scraped_info).hexdigest()
```

This has the added advantage that the MD5 hash is always going to be calculated the same regardless of OS or system architecture; `hash()` can offer no such guarantee.